# Successful use of websockets with Glassfish and a rich component interface

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, websocket

Has anyone successfully implmented a Glassfish 3.1 server with websockets and a rich component interface for JSF like RichFaces, IceFaces, PrimeFaces.  And If so what is the easiest method or best way to do this? Primefaces requires Jetty, and I think IceFaces uses JMS.

I'm just trying to find a way to add server push from Glassfish to my view that will display a text stream as it is available in the client. I'd like to do this through a component UI of JSF but if it's possible to circumvent the framework while still being able to use it for it's javascript management and UI utilities that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish 3.1 is broken in terms of WebSocket implementation and support a really old version of the protocol. I recommend you try the 3.1.2 version. If you want to be "shielded" from Websocket/Glassfish changes, take a look at the [Atmosphere Framework](http://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). The framework take care of all those change.

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: And it looks like I'm actually using 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

why not using IceFaces for that? I do not know what does it use internally, but they have ServerPush. The library that is doing this is called IcePush. IceFaces are integrated with IcePush. 
See http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Ajax+Push+-+Overview
AFAIK now they are using long polling, but I hope they will switch to web socket as soon as it will be ready for enterprice.

Comment: I need websocket suppot. Long polling wont work for me on this project.